# How to connect 2 different power supplies together

Tags: power-supply, ground, output

I have a power supply that provide the following outputs (+&-15V) & (+&-10V) sadly this power supply is obsolete so I have to get those voltages from two separate power supplies one that will provide (+&-15V) and another that will provide (+&-10V)the problem is how to connect the 0V because in the machine there is one (0V) from the old power supply now I have two , so should I connect them together ?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer is probably yes, you should connect them together.  If the old supply was not isolated, and you replace it with two non-isolated supplies, then the grounds will be connected together anyway through the supply ground.  If the old supply was isolated, you need to replace it with isolated supplies and connect the grounds together.

Make sure the supplies are fully compatible, it's not just a case of having the right voltage. Make sure the isolation is the same or better, the maximum current on each rail is the same or larger, the minimum current for stability is the same or smaller etc.